# Add angular in a spring boot application

Tags: java, angularjs, spring-boot, bower

I want to integrate angularjs in my spring boot project. For that I added bower to my project. Then I made bower install angular. and now can see the angular package.

My questions:

1- Is the app.js generated automatically or have I to create it my self?

2- How can I add the angular-route? By bower? Or by download it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look here => https://angularjs.org/ or here => http://websystique.com/springmvc/spring-mvc-4-angularjs-example/ you'll find useful informations.

1 - The app.js is mostly your work.

2 - You can use Bower, or download. It's up to you.

Comment: I have already find this. But I confused on how to apply it in my project. Can you please clarify each answer of my two questions?

Comment: 2 - You can use Bower, or download. It's up to you.

Comment: so for the app.js it's not a problem if I created by myself. Isn't it?

Comment: Yup, exactly ;-)

Comment: Thank you :) can you please edit your answer by adding the two answers of my questions? (just for anyone else having the same issue ;-) )